# How to install a downloaded backend theme in Odoo 11

Tags: odoo

I am new to Odoo.I have downloaded a backend theme (https://apps.odoo.com/apps/themes/11.0/itm_material/).Can anyone tell how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what backend theme you've downloaded but usually, you have to paste the theme folder into your addons folder then go to ODOO settings, activate developer mode, go to apps and click on update apps list and then search for your theme and then install it.

Answer (score -1):

Themes are like any module, you just have to install it.
Then, "Go To: Settings > Users & Companies > Companies > Apps Theme Dashboard". This is from the module documentation that you linked.

Comment: Thank you for your much more helpful answer.